# Updating Identity column from INT to BigInt

Tags: sql-server

I have a table which has an Identity field and is INT data type. The max value in the column is 2,143,352,421 and so nightly jobs are crashing.

I need to change it to BigInt. However, this particular column is a primary key, with associated foreign keys. It also has indexes associated.

My process to convert this data type to BigInt is:

- Un-associate the Primary Key.
- Alter Table, Alter Column to change data type to BigInt.
- Re-associate the primary key relationships

How do I undo the primary key, so I maintain the records in the table?

Is this as simple as dropping the primary key, changing the column type to bigint, then re-establishing the PK?

Thanks.

Comment: If you try to drop the primary key constraint you will get an error, you're gonna have to drop the foreign key constraint before the PK

Answer (score 3):

This gives me a giggle as my company went through the exact same thing a few months back. This is what we did:

- Drop all FK that reference the PK
- Alter these FK columns to `bigint` (a painful lesson after things went live)
- Drop the PK index
- Alter the PK column to `bigint`
- Recreate the PK
- Recreate the FKs

Comment: And if possible put the datbase in single user mode while you do this.

Comment: And if that is in any mean a non trivial database make sure you time that on a staging platform first - this can take HOURS on a non trivial database and you do not want to run out of your maintenance schedule.